# How to GET nested data from server in Angular App?

Tags: angular, api, angular-services

I have problem with write specific data in component. I loaded parents data (brands) from api but childs data (models) i don't know how load from api. This data I GET from server to console:

[image]

and this show me at the monitor: [image].

In the console I have this ERROR: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

Do you know how resolve this? Thank you for your help.

My code:

app.component.ts

```
vehicleLists: VehicleLists[] = [];

  constructor(
    private vehicleService: VehicleService,
    private router: Router,
    private vehicleListAdapter: ListAdapter,
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getLists();
  }

  public getLists() {
    this.vehicleService.getVehicleLists().subscribe(({ brands, models }) => {
      console.log(brands);
      this.vehicleLists = brands;
      models.map(model =>
        this.vehicleLists.push(this.vehicleListAdapter.adapt(model)));
    });
  }
```

app.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of vehicleLists">
  <p>{{item.id}} - {{item.name}}</p>
    <p>{{item.models}}</p>
</div>
```

lists.ts - model

```
export class VehicleLists {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  models: VehicleModel[];
}

export class VehicleModel {
  name: string;
  description: string;
}
```

vehicle-list.adapter.ts

```
export class ListAdapter implements Adapter<VehicleLists> {
  adapt(item: any): VehicleLists {
    const obj = new VehicleLists();
    obj.name = item.name;
    obj.id = item.id;
    obj.models = item.models;
    return obj;
  }
}
```

vehicle.service.ts

```
getVehicleLists() {
    return this.http.get<any>(environment.ApiUrl + `/api/url`);
  }
```

Comment: Can you post complete API response from network tab

Comment: yes, it's at the top of post.

Comment: export class VehicleLists {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  models: Array<VehicleModel>;
}

export class VehicleModel {
  name: string;
  description: string;
}

vehicleList: Array<VehicleLists>;

Comment: and in .subscribe(result: Array<VehicleLists>) =>{
this.vehicleLists = result;
}

and your variable vehicleLists should also be of type Array<VehicleLists>.

Comment: I try your solution but I have this error -> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error `ERROR: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` is coming from `models.map` in:

```js
public getLists() {
  this.vehicleService.getVehicleLists().subscribe(({ brands, models }) => {
    console.log(brands);
    this.vehicleLists = brands;
    models.map(model =>
      this.vehicleLists.push(this.vehicleListAdapter.adapt(model)));
  });
}
```

Your reference to `models` is `undefined` because is is nested inside of each object in the `brands` array and unable to be unpacked in the subscribe `{ brands, models }`.

`brands` is an array of multiple objects, say a `brand`, that each has a key `models`, which is also an array of objects that we can call a `model`. You would need to iterate through the array of brands to get to each array of models.

What about something like this?

```js
public getLists() {
  this.vehicleService.getVehicleLists().subscribe(({ brands }) => {
    console.log(brands); 
    this.vehicleLists = brands;
    brands.forEach(brand => {
      brand.models.map(model => {
        this.vehicleLists.push(this.vehicleListAdapter.adapt(model));
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Note: You are pushing to `this.vehicleLists` which will now have all of the brands (with the nested models) and the models that you are adapting. That is up to you to decide what you want the final data to look like.

Comment: Thank you. Now I haven't error but when i want write nested data I still have this [object Object] and not data what i want from VehicleModel. How I correct write this nested data?

Comment: Can you share what an example of the `model` object looks like? It is is something like `model = { name: 'r8'  } ` and you render `model` in a template, you'll get `object Object`. You would need to render `model.name`.

Comment: yes, for exmp. this is object inside brands.models from api: `62: {name: "R8", description: "R8"}`, for this I made model: `export class VehicleLists {id: string;name: string;models: VehicleModel[];}` and `export class VehicleModel { name: string; description: string;}`